# How to spread props using Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am using a nested component and I would like to set the whole `data` property for that nested component with a value from the parent component.

For instance, first `app.html` component

```
<NestedComponent data="{{ forNested }}" />
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return { forNested: { a: 1, b, 2 }};
    }
  };
</script>
```

Then the nested component, `nested-component.html`, would be:

```
<p>Hi {{ a }} and {{ b }}</p>
```

Instead this means I have to do this:

```
<p>Hi {{ data.a }} and {{ data.b }}</p>
```

Is there some sort of keyword attribute to do this?

---

**Update**

Since there is no spread operator I did something like this, where you can set an arbitrarily field, like `data` and then observe that to update all properties.  In the nested component:

```
<div class="stuff">{{ someProperty }}</div>
<script>
export default {
  oncreate: function() {
    // Allow data to set all propeties, since we can't set
    // all from the markup of a component
    this.observe('data', d => {
      if (_.isPlainObject(d)) {
        this.set(d);
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Then when using that nested component, where `forNestedObject` is something like `{ someProperty: 123 }`:

```
<NestedComponent data="{{ forNestedObject }}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a 'spread operator' like `<NestedComponent ...forNested>`, though it's not inconceivable that we'd add something like that in future. For now, the most concise way to pass data down is to use the `:foo` directive, which means `foo={{foo}}`:

```html
<NestedComponent :a :b/>
```

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if this is implemented already? This would be very useful to pass through props to deep level components.

Comment: It is, yes — you can do `<NestedComponent {...props}/>`. Docs [here](https://v3.svelte.technology/tutorial/spread-props) (relates to version 3, which will be the stable version in a few days)

Answer (score 4):

> Actually I just tried and **YES** you can spread props.

**Parent Component**

```
<script>
  import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld.svelte";
  let allProps = {
    first: 'First prop',
    second: 'Second prop'
  };
</script>

<HelloWorld {...allProps} />
```

**Child Component**

```
<script>
    export let first;
    export let second;
</script>

First prop: {first} <br>
Second prop: {second}
```

[See it in action (Codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/spread-props-using-svelte-y7xou)

Answer (score 1):

I use [babel + spread operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread), this is worked for me:

(svelte version: 2.16.1)

```
    {#each grid as row}
        {#each row as cell}
            <Cell {...cell} />
        {/each}
    {/each}
```

how it will look after babel conversion:

```
    {#each grid as row}
        {#each row as cell}
            <Cell {letter: cell.letter, nRow: cell.nRow, nCol: cell.nCol} />
        {/each}
    {/each}
```

in svelte this [is equivalent](https://svelte.technology/guide#props) to the following:

```
    {#each grid as row}
        {#each row as cell}
            <Cell letter={cell.letter} nRow={cell.nRow} nCol={cell.nCol} />
        {/each}
    {/each}
```

Maybe it will work without babel